# The selected GPT formatted disk contains a partition which is not of type 'PARTITION_BASIC_DATA_GUID'

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

I want to extend my "C" disk on Windows 10 (second partition from screen below). In order to do this, I plan to move data from disk "D" (fourth partition from screen below) to new partition created from "Unallocated" space that I have right now. Then I'll remove 3rd and 4th partitions and extend size of 2nd one.

Unfortunately there is some problem with creating partition on unallocated space.

Full error:

> The selected GPT formatted disk contains a partition which is not of type 'PARTITION_BASIC_DATA_GUID' and is both proceeded and followed by a partition of type 'PARTITION_BASIC_DATA_GUID'

Screenshot:

[image]

How my partitions look like:

[image]

Comment: I'm somewhat confused as to why Windows considers that to be an _error_. It ought to be a normal situation... Could you perhaps download [gdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/files/gptfdisk/1.0.1/gdisk-binaries/), run `gdisk 0:`, and post the output of its `p` command?

Comment: Same issue here... I installed Fedora Workstation to this partition, but now I've wiped out that entire partition and I'm looking to merge partition to my main partition.